# Cakephp: record random once a day

Tags: cakephp, random

how can I have random results that change only after 24 hours?

```
 $random = $this->Post->find('first',array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Post.active'=>1,
        ),
        'order' => 'rand()',
    ));
    $this->view($random['Post']['id']);
    $this->render('view');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a seed for the `rand()` function based on the current date.

```
$random = $this->Post->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Post.active' => 1,
    ),
    'order' => 'rand(' . date('Ymd') . ')',
));
```

Alternatively, cache the result and refresh the cache once daily.

Comment: I get the following error: 'Database Error Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column "1431993600" in order clause SQL Query: SELECT Item.item_state_id, Item.title, Item.slug, Item.id, Item.parent_id, Item.presentation, Item.image, Item.image_dir, Item.tag_title FROM enjoytoscana_01.vnt_items AS Item WHERE Item.parent_id = 63 AND Item.item_state_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND(1431993600) ASC LIMIT 12 Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/pdo_error.ctp'

Comment: Does the code in your original post work? Eg, does `'order' => 'rand()'` work? I don't see how my code can fail if your original code works. You might have to add the `rand()` to the select, or simply change it to `SELECT *`